# Starting an app in debug mode from another app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am launching App B from App A with intent.  I want to see debug mode logs in App B. If I launch App B directly I can do it. But if I have to launch it from App A, I cannot use debug. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: no. this can not be done

Answer (score 1):

**To see logs:**
Make sure you have Logcat opened and go to combo to switch between your debug apps are running currently to see each app's logs.

[image]

**To enable debug mode:**
You need to have both projects opened together and once you have launched App-B from App-A as you are doing, when App-B will be opened, you can attach debug mode from "Attach Debugger to Android Process" button on its own "Android Project B":

[image]

Tested on Android Studio 3.4

If it is not this, maybe we need more details...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. The official way is to set your breakpoint and then use this in your onCreate method:

```
            Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

This pauses the app until a debugger is attached, at which point it will hit your breakpoint.

Alternatively you can put a sleep timer in your onCreate method, (e.g. TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30)), which pauses your app long enough for you to attach a debugger.